# Oracle Apex PRC not ending

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

in Oracle Apex I've build a process to update data in my database. Here ist the pl/sql expression

```
begin
  :P4021_ID := org_portal_admin_aws_user.pkg_org_admin_skill.fnc_iu_skill(:P4021_ID, :P4021_KATEGORIE, :P4021_NAME, :P4021_STATUS);
end;
```

Why is the page in a endlees loding loop?

The timeout message:

```
Failure of server APACHE bridge:

No backend server available for connection: timed out after 10 seconds or idempotent set to OFF or method not idempotent.
```

Comment: It would be difficult to tell until you share your code for `pkg_org_admin_skill.fnc_iu_skill` with us.

Comment: @XING from the error message I doubt that function is even being run: the request is not reaching the database at all.  Config issue, not code.

Comment: Could it be possible that there is a Reverse Proxy in between that has a timeout of 10 seconds?